# Bad Request from Creating a New Order with Klarna

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, e-commerce, klarna

I'm getting a Bad Request when I'm sending a POST request to the Klarna API to create a new order.

This is my code for sending the POST request:

```
Cart = new CartManager(_context, HttpContext.Session).GetCart();
Customer = new CustomerManager(HttpContext.Session).GetCustomer()
OrderViewModel order = new OrderViewModel();

order.Reference = DateTime.Now.ToOADate().ToString().Replace(",", string.Empty);
order.Cart = Cart;
order.Customer = Customer;

string url = ApiHelper.KlarnaApiClient.BaseAddress + "checkout/v3/orders";

KlarnaOrderModel klarnaOrderModel = new KlarnaOrderModel
{
    purchase_currency = "SEK",
    order_amount = (int)order.Cart.TotalCharge,
    order_lines = klarnaOrderLines
};

HttpResponseMessage response = await ApiHelper.KlarnaApiClient.PostAsJsonAsync(
        url, klarnaOrderModel);

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

KlarnaOrderModel:

```
public class KlarnaOrderModel
{
public string purchase_country { get { return "SE"; } }
public string purchase_currency { get; set; }
public string locale { get { return "en-GB"; } }
public int order_amount { get; set; }
public int order_tax_amount { get { return 2500; } }
public List<KlarnaOrderLine> order_lines { get; set; }
public KlarnaMerchantUrls merchant_urls { get { return new Models.KlarnaMerchantUrls(); } }
}
```

KlarnaOrderLine:

```
public class KlarnaOrderLine
{
public string name { get; set; }
public int quantity { get; set; }
public int unit_price { get; set; }
public int tax_rate { get { return 2500; } }
public int total_amount { get { return unit_price * quantity; } }
public int total_tax_amount { get { return total_amount / 5 ; } }
}
```

KlarnaMerchantUrls:

```
public class KlarnaMerchantUrls
{
public string terms { get { return "https://localhost:44316/shop/terms"; } }
public string checkout { get { return "https://localhost:44316/shop/checkout"; } }
public string confirmation { get { return "https://localhost:44316/shop/checkout/confirmation"; } 
public string push { get { return "https://localhost:44316/shop/push"; } }
}
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

My code for initializing the API:

```
KlarnaApiClient = new HttpClient();

KlarnaApiClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.playground.klarna.com/");

KlarnaApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
KlarnaApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
KlarnaApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{MY KLARNA API KEY UID}:{MY KLARNA API KEY PASSWORD}")));
```

Comment: I do not have an answer to give you, this is something you have to debug from your side. Try deserializing the response to see if there are any details returned about what you did wrong and got a BadRequest

Comment: Thank you!  I followed your advice and it turns out the problem was the line public int order_tax_amount { get { return 2500; } } I had misunderstood this property. I thought it should be a constant 2500 if the tax rate is 25%.